# How to realise this notebox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm just looking for doing a note like this, is it done with tabular?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Please have a look into the manuals of these two packages: a) with "classical LaTeX" https://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl, b) with Tikz https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox .

Comment: It is done probably with some `list`(like `itemize` with redefined items labels) inserted into `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with [Tcolorbox](https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf). For fine tuning of lists see e.g. the [Wikibook on Latex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[% passing options here
    title=Exercise 1.1,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!40!yellow!30, % think of mixing 2 colors with sliders
    arc=0mm % sharp corners
 ]
 Let's start with some intro, here with an ordinary list:
 
 \begin{itemize}
  \item first item here first item here first item here first item here first item here first item here 
  \item second one goes here
 \end{itemize}
 
 \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

#### P.S.

Designing fancy lists is possible, and requires some work. So for simplicity the code below adds a desription-environment, which does some of the bold formatting by itself, as a kind of approximation, a trade-off between coding effort and result.

It also uses package `pifont` to provide some ding-symbols. The [comprehensive list of Latex symbols](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) provides many more alternatives, also indicating how to use them in code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pifont}     % provides the symbols for a pen and check

\begin{document}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[% passing options here
    title=Exercise 1.1,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!40!yellow!30, % think of mixing 2 colors with sliders
    arc=0mm % sharp corners
 ]
 Let's start with some intro, here with an ordinary list:
 
 \begin{itemize}
  \item first item here first item here first item here first item here first item here first item here 
  \item second one goes here
 \end{itemize} 
 \end{tcolorbox}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \bigskip
 And now let's see how to approach the list of your example a bit more using a description environment.
 
 \begin{tcolorbox}[% passing options here
    title=Exercise 1.1,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!40!yellow!30, % think of mixing 2 colors with sliders
    arc=0mm % sharp corners
 ]
 Let's start with some intro, here with an ordinary list:
 
 \begin{description}
   \item[\ding{46} Start with something] first item here first item here first item here first item here first item here first item here 
  \item[\ding{51} End with something else] second one goes here
 \end{description} 
 \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: You may number the box automatically

Comment: Sure: One step at a time when you are a beginner ;-)